# Linux не дает разрешение на выполнение скрипта

Tags: python, linux, centos, centos7, zabbix

Ситуация следующая. Есть allertscript для zabbix написанный на python.
Выглядит следующим образом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Скрипт помещается на zabbix в /usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/
Затем настраивается allertscript с параметрами: {ALERT.SENDTO}, 
{ALERT.SUBJECT} и {ALERT.MESSAGE}
В SENDTO передается директория баззы данных.

Инициируется при срабатывании тригера, проходиться по пользователям в 
БД, и если хост есть в списке, отправляем уведомление.
"""
import sys
import sqlite3
import requests

TOKEN = 'my_token'


def get_server(text):
    text = text.split('\\n')
    for i in text:
        if "Host" in i:
            result = i.replace("Host: ", "")
    return result


def send(user, text):
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TOKEN +  '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + user + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + text
    requests.get(send_text)


def get_users(server, db_loc):
    users = []
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_loc)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT id, sub_servers FROM users')
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    con.close()

    for i in data:
        info = []
        for j in i:
            info.append(j)
        if server in info[1]:
            users.append(info[0])
    return users


def start():
    db = str(sys.argv[1])
    subj = sys.argv[2]
    message = sys.argv[3]

    server = get_server(message)
    users = get_users(server, db)
    print(users)

    if users:
        for i in users:
            send(i, subj + "\n" + message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

При срабатывании скрипта из консоли, все ок. Но при попытке запустить тест из забикса, выдает следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понимаю, CentOS не дает доступа к открытию БД. Делал chown на zabbix, chmod на 777. Результат тот-же.

Как решить эту проблему?
Спасибо!

Comment: `print(db_loc)` ?

Comment: db = str(sys.argv[1]) получение параметров из аргументов переданных на скрипт. А аргументы точно передаются? А сам файл бд по указанному пути существует? А какой это путь? относительный или абсолютный?

Answer (score 0):

Решил!
Всем спасибо за отклик.

Все оказалось банально, решилось когда прописал полный путь до БД

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ решением.